# How to determine size of c_long in .NET (independent of runtime and OS)?

Tags: c#, python, c++, .net, mono

How to determine size of C/C++ long type in .NET (independent of runtime and OS)? This long type can be 32-bit or 64-bit depending on OS.

Some of you asked why this is needed? Generally, when calling from managed to native code on that platform.

In Python this is possible like this:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_long)
8


Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

In [1]: import ctypes
In [2]: ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_long)
Out[2]: 4
```

Comment: Since length of `long` in c/c++ is implementation specific it is unclear what you actually want to get as result...

Comment: when embedding cpython runtime in .NET: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/pull/376

Comment: more generally when calling from managed into native code on that platform

Comment: @dsgdfg all MSVC++ runtimes are 32-bit c_long, but I'm also interested in other platforms - see tags.